# TabControl background image over background

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I have TabControl:

```
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="local:ucTabItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ucTabItem">
                            <Grid Name="Panel" >
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    Margin="1,2"/>
                                <Grid.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Sudanese_Police.png" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="None" />
                                </Grid.Background>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource brushTabHeaderActive}" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource brushTabHeaderHover}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
    </TabControl>
```

How can I set the background image that will shown when all tabs is closed I try to use

```
<TabControl.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/BGI.png" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="None" />
</TabControl.Background>
```

But then I dont see background color...

Comment: What is ucTabItem? How do you populate the TabControl? And when and where do you want the image to be displayed? You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: something like `<Trigger Property="Items.Count" Value="0">` on the TabControl's triggers